# I lost all of my saved passwords in Google/Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

Just noticed in Chrome that I don't have all my saved passwords, and went to Google website (Manage Passwords) to check if maybe it was Chrome issue, but they were lost as well.

I'm afraid that my passwords has been stolen, is there any way to recover them? And to check how I lost them?

Should I report this suspicious activity to Google? And how?

Comment: perhaps you used a utility like Ccleaner to delete them.

Comment: Were you signed into chrome? If so are you signed in now.

Comment: Regarding "stealing", I think data thieves more often just copy the data than remove your copy of it (since reading is more likely to succeed than removal, and the risk of being noticed is way smaller if nothing changes in the target system), so having some data vanish isn't especially credible symptom of data theft.